# mocha console log shows object promise

Tags: selenium, mocha.js

Starting to get a grip on mocha but one thing I do not understand, in the code below

```
describe('03 Test recent recipe test', () => {
    it('Test search async', async () => {
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name('selectit')));
        var recipeName = driver.findElement(By.name('selectit')).getText(); 
        driver.findElement(By.name('selectit')).click();
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('name')));
        var recipeLabel = driver.findElement(By.id('name')).getText(); 
        await console.log(recipeName + " - " + recipeLabel);
        expect(recipeName).to.contain(recipeLabel);
    });
  });
```

This test returns as a pass but the console.log outputs - [object Promise] - [object Promise]
Why is this, the expect test is happy they match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you misused the `await` on the `console.log()` statement.

You should `await` when you're getting `recipeName` and `recipeLabel` because `getText()` returns a `Promise`.

Since `console.log()` doesn't return a `Promise` you don't need to `await` it.

As a side note here, by `await`ing for the `console.log()` statement, it won't resolve the promises inside it.

Your code should look like this:

```
describe('03 Test recent recipe test', () => {
    it('Test search async', async () => {
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.name('selectit')));
        var recipeName = await driver.findElement(By.name('selectit')).getText(); 
        await driver.findElement(By.name('selectit')).click();
        await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('name')));
        var recipeLabel = await driver.findElement(By.id('name')).getText(); 
        console.log(recipeName + " - " + recipeLabel);
        expect(recipeName).to.contain(recipeLabel);
    });
  });
```

To use the variables as you have them and print using `console.log()` you can `await` each one of them inside:

```
    var recipeName = driver.findElement(By.name('selectit')).getText(); 
    ....
    var recipeLabel = driver.findElement(By.id('name')).getText(); 
    console.log(await recipeName + " - " + await recipeLabel);
```